# Python Decorator inside class

Tags: python, python-3.x, wrapper, pysftp

I have a class that basically connects to an SFTP server, not too relevant to the question.
I am trying to create a wrapper function/decorator that would help me eliminate a lot of repetitive code.
This is a working version of the piece of code:

```
def upload_file(self, local_file, destionation_path: str):
    with pysftp.Connection(
            host=self.host,
            username=self.username,
            password=self.password,
            cnopts=self.cnopts
    ) as sftp:
        local_file_path = local_file
        print(f'Uploading output file: {local_file_path} to remote location: {destionation_path}')
        sftp.put(
            localpath=local_file_path,
            remotepath=destionation_path,
            confirm=False
        )
```

I would prefer not to have to write the `with pysftp.... as sftp' part in the beginning of every function.
I tried to approach the problem like this:

```
def connection(self, function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        connection = pysftp.Connection(
            host=self.host,
            username=self.username,
            password=self.password,
            cnopts=self.cnopts
        )
        return_val = function(connection, *args, **kwargs)
        return return_val
    return wrapper

@connection
def upload_file(self, connection, local_file, destionation_path: str):
        print(f'Uploading output file: {local_file} to remote location: {destionation_path}')
        connection.put(
            localpath=local_file,
            remotepath=destionation_path,
            confirm=False
        )
```

But then again, if it is declare like this the self parameter cant be passed to the wrapper, and how do I call the upload_file from somewhere else? Since the connection param is instantiated by the decorator.
If this should be done any other way I would really appreciate some guidelines as I'm not even sure what I am looking for.

Comment: That's a typical use of constructors. Why do you want to create a decorator?

Comment: This isn't equivalent, you*should* use the context manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` should go as an argument in the `wrapper` function:

```
def connection(function):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with pysftp.Connection(
            host=self.host,
            username=self.username,
            password=self.password,
            cnopts=self.cnopts
        ) as connection:
            return_val = function(connection, *args, **kwargs)
            return return_val
    return wrapper
```

Anyways, you could pass the connection to the constructor as @pqans said. It's the simplest solution and what I would've done. I think you are complicating a bit.

Use the context manager to inject the dependency  at runtime:

```
with pysftp.Connection(
            host=self.host,
            username=self.username,
            password=self.password,
            cnopts=self.cnopts
        ) as connection:

    sftp = MyClass(connection)
    sftp.upload_file(local_file, destionation_path)
```

An alternative would be to make a context manager for your class and use the dependency injection pattern:

```
class ContextWrapperClass(object):
    def __init__(self, my_ftp_class_instance, *args, **kwargs):
        # ... Some code here

        self.ftp_operations = my_ftp_class_instance # This could be an instance 

    def __enter__(self):
        self.connection = pysftp.Connection(
            host=self.host,
            username=self.username,
            password=self.password,
            cnopts=self.cnopts
        )
        self.ftp_operations.connection = self.connection
        return self.ftp_operations

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print("Exception has been handled")
        self.connection.close()
        return True
```

then you would use it as:

```
with ContextWrapperClass(MyClass()) as sftp:
    # connection is inserted as dependency injection on constructor
    sftp.upload_file(local_file, destionation_path)
```